# Command for switching exercise styles

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to create a command that allows me (or the user) to switch between two different styles for typesetting problems. One is the runin in the margin, while the other one is defined by `subsection`

- Is there a simple way to obtain consistent spacing for the two styles?
- In particular I want the runin style to start on the same line regardless of whether there is a blank line below or not. Also it would be nice if the space before `\problem` was the same regardless of style.

As can be seen in the image the second problem has a newline too much.

[image]

Is there a way for

```
\Problem
\lipsum[66]
```

and

```
\Problem

\lipsum[66]
```

to produce the same output?

- While not really the question the same output would be great in an enumerate environment. However, I was not able to emulate the `\subsection` apperance using a `\item`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inline} \settoggle{inline}{true}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\Problem}{%
    \stepcounter{problem}%
    \iftoggle{inline}{%
        \bigskip

        \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\protect\fbox{\theproblem}\qquad}%
        %\vspace{-\baselineskip}
        }{%
        \subsection*{Problem~\theproblem}%
    }%
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\Problem
\lipsum[66]

\Problem

\lipsum[66]

\settoggle{inline}{false}

\Problem

\lipsum[66]

\Problem
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

Comment: \section etc. use \@afterheading to affect the next paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `\par`s act the same as one `\par` (blank line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inline} \settoggle{inline}{true}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\Problem}{%
    \stepcounter{problem}%
    \iftoggle{inline}{%
        \bigskip\par
        \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\protect\fbox{\theproblem}\qquad}%
        \par\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip-\parskip
        }{%
        \subsection*{Problem~\theproblem}%
    }%
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\Problem
\lipsum[66]

\Problem

\lipsum[66]

\settoggle{inline}{false}

\Problem

\lipsum[66]

\Problem
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```